# page before url / change url

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I created a login website, and my URL became like this

```
http://localhost/koperasi/index.php/cukl/index
```

how to make my url like...

```
http://localhost/koperasi/index.php/cukl
```

because I want to make a crud program but I think I have a problem in the url

**
my previous program using `http://localhost/lee/index.php/buku`
 so my page can entered CRUD on `http://localhost/lee/index.php/buku/ubah`

but now my newer program url is `http://localhost/koperasi/index.php/cukl/index`


how and where to change the url? is in the controller? model? or view?

Comment: Try look into .htaccess URL rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

I think, firstly you have to add an htaccess file which will remove index.php in your URL.

and inside the route.php file, you can define a new URL which you want.

Like this.

```
$route['cukl'] = 'cukl/index';
```